# DoubleClickTime becomes zero when running on buildAgent

Tags: .net, windows-10, windows-services

We are using SandDock in windows for windows Forms docking,
since Updating to **Windows 10 2004**, we have unittest failing due to some sanddock logic, In Sanddock code, we can see it is the DoubleClickTime that is set to zero (0).

- When logged on the machine with the windows user the buildagent is running as, the double click time is 500 (default)
- When running from the buildagent service, the doubleclickTime becomes zero (0)

Powershell testcode:

```
[void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
[System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation]::DoubleClickTime
```

From Desktop Output=500, from Service, Output = 0

Any idea how to revert behavior so doubleClickTime is identical between desktop and service execution?